# Send Perform Message with Record

Tags: delphi

I can send a message to a Form in the same application using:
    `Form.Perform(MW_setFunction,0,0);`
and that works fine.

I cannot figure out how to send a Record Struct through the LParam and recover it at the other end.
Using Windows 10 32 and 64 bit with Rio
Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To send you do this:

```
var
  MyRec: TMyRec;
....
Form.Perform(MW_setFunction, 0, LParam(@MyRec));
```

And when receiving you would do this:

```
var
  MyRec: PMyRec; // where PMyRec = ^TMyRec
....
MyRec := PMyRec(Msg.lParam);
```

or

```
var
  MyRec: TMyRec;
....
MyRec := PMyRec(Msg.lParam)^;
```

or

Of course you don't need to copy to a local variable, you can pass directly to a function:

```
DoSomething(PMyRec(Msg.lParam)^);
```

You can even use a value cast rather than a pointer cast:

```
TMyRec(Pointer(Msg.lParam)^)
```

Comment: There is an overloaded `Perform` method showing this technique with a `TRect`.